# How to scroll down to content box in this video style with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a page with video styles - http://picovico.com/video-styles/ in my WordPress. Everything is working fine, except that I would like to scroll down to content when the thumbnails are clicked. Right now the content box is opening but the window is not scrolling down to it. Actually I am using a plugin called expand grid. I am not getting support from the plugin author.

I am using bellow code:

```
$(".cq-expandgrid-item").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".cq-expandgrid-content").offset().top
    }, 5000);
});
```

Thanks.

@TTCC Here's the init.min.js present in the plugin file. The code is given below. With your help, I hope I can locate and add the code you suggested now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
a(".cq-expandgrid").each(function(b, c) {
    function r() {
        o = setInterval(function() {
            clearInterval(o), k++, k > m && (k = 0), a(".cq-expandgrid-toggle", p).eq(k).trigger("click"), r()
        }, 1e3 * j)
    }
    var d = a(this),
        e = a(this).data("itemsize"),
        f = "yes" == a(this).data("transparentitem") ? !0 : !1,
        g = a(this).data("labelfontsize"),
        h = a(this).data("subfontsize"),
        i = parseInt(a(this).data("itemheight"), 10),
        j = parseInt(a(this).data("autoslide"), 10),
        k = 0,
        m = a(".cq-expandgrid-item", d).length,
        n = "yes" == a(this).data("openfirst") ? !1 : !0,
        o = 0,
        p = a(".cq-expandgrid-item", d).each(function(b) {
            a(this).data("index", b);
            var c = a(this).data("image"),
                d = a(this).data("avatar"),
                f = a(this).data("backgroundcolor"),
                j = a(this).data("iconcolor"),
                k = a(this).data("iconsize"),
                l = a(this).data("contentcolor"),
                m = a(this).data("labelcolor"),
                n = a(this).data("subtitlecolor"),
                o = a(this).data("bgstyle"),
                p = a(this).data("avatartype"),
                q = a(this),
                r = a(this).attr("title");
            if (r && "" !== r) var r = a(".cq-expandgrid-face", q).tooltipster({
                content: r,
                position: "top",
                delay: 200,
                interactive: !0,
                speed: 300,
                touchDevices: !0,
                animation: "grow",
                theme: "tooltipster-shadow",
                contentAsHTML: !0
            });
            "" != l && a(".cq-expandgrid-text, .cq-expandgrid-text p, .cq-expandgrid-text h2, .cq-expandgrid-text h3, .cq-expandgrid-text h4, .cq-expandgrid-text h5, .cq-expandgrid-text h6", q).css("color", l), "" != m && a(".cq-expandgrid-title", q).css("color", m), "" != n && a(".cq-expandgrid-subtitle", q).css("color", n), "" != g && a(".cq-expandgrid-title", q).css("font-size", g), "" != h && a(".cq-expandgrid-subtitle", q).css("font-size", h), i > 0 && "customized" == e && a(".cq-expandgrid-face", q).css("height", i), "" != f && "customized" == o && a(".cq-expandgrid-face", q).css("background-color", f), "" != j && a(".cq-expandgrid-icon", q).css("color", j), "" != k && a(".cq-expandgrid-icon", q).css("font-size", k), "" != c && "undefined" != c && c && a(".cq-expandgrid-face", q).css({
                "background-image": "url(" + c + ")"
            }), "image" == p && "" != d && "undefined" != d && d && a(".cq-expandgrid-avatar", q).css({
                "background-image": "url(" + d + ")"
            })
        }),
        q = null;
    d.on("mouseover", function(a) {
        clearInterval(o)
    }).on("mouseleave", function(a) {
        j > 0 && r()
    }), a(".cq-expandgrid-toggle", p).click(function() {
        var b = a(this).closest(".cq-expandgrid-item");
        b.data("backgroundcolor");
        if (k = b.data("index"), clearInterval(o), q && !b.is(q)) {
            q.removeClass("cq-expandgrid-openstate").addClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate"), f && p.removeClass("outfoucs");
            var d = a("iframe", q).attr("src");
            d && "" != d && (d.indexOf("youtube") > -1 || d.indexOf("vimeo") > -1) && (a("iframe", q).attr("src", ""), a("iframe", q).attr("src", d))
        }
        b.hasClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate") ? (q = b.removeClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate").addClass("cq-expandgrid-openstate"), p.not(b).hasClass("outfoucs") || f && p.not(b).addClass("outfoucs")) : (b.removeClass("cq-expandgrid-openstate").addClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate"), f && p.not(b).removeClass("outfoucs"))
    }), (n || j > 0) && a(".cq-expandgrid-toggle", p).eq(0).trigger("click"), j > 0 && r(), p.find(".cq-expandgrid-close").click(function() {
        var b = a(this).closest(".cq-expandgrid-item");
        b.removeClass("cq-expandgrid-openstate").addClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate"), p.not(b).removeClass("outfoucs")
    })
})
```

});

@TTCC, Here's the code I implemented as per your suggestion:

```
b.hasClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate") ? (q = b.removeClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate").addClass("cq-expandgrid-openstate"), p.not(b).hasClass("outfoucs") || f && p.not(b).addClass("outfoucs")) : (b.removeClass("cq-expandgrid-openstate").addClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate"), f && p.not(b).removeClass("outfoucs")), b.hasClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate") && a('body').stop().animate({scrollTop: b.find(".cq-expandgrid-content").offset().top - 50 }, 500);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code has two script tag in your page, and this error make code can not run.

Actually, you don't need to write a piece of code alone, and just move it to the "cq-expandgrid-toggle" click event in vc-extensions-expandgrid/js/init.min.js" file.

You can use jQuery.animate() and scrollTop property to achieve it.

Replace code in init.min.js file from line 63 to 65 (before "})") by my code below:

```
b.hasClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate") ? (a('body').stop().animate({scrollTop: b.find(".cq-expandgrid-content").offset().top - 0}, 200),q = b.removeClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate").addClass("cq-expandgrid-openstate"), p.not(b).hasClass("outfoucs") || f && p.not(b).addClass("outfoucs"))
                    : (b.removeClass("cq-expandgrid-openstate").addClass("cq-expandgrid-initstate"), f && p.not(b).removeClass("outfoucs"));
```

"500" is a number determining in millisecond how long the animation will run, and you can change it as your wish.

And remove transition style of .cq-expandgrid-content in /wp-content/plugins/vc-extensions-expandgrid/css/style.css file (about line 378).

```
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ttccmvp/3sgthbeL/) is a jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi @TTCC, You mean something like this in vc-extensions-expandgrid/js/init.js? : 

`$(".cq-expandgrid-item").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".cq-expandgrid-content").offset().top
        }, 5000);
    });`

I am not getting any result infact.

Comment: I can't see your source code, and I just beautify your "http://picovico.com/wp-content/plugins/vc-extensions-expandgrid/js/init.min.js" file, which contain a click event on ".cq-expandgrid-toggle" dom.You can search ".cq-expandgrid-toggle" to find it, and insert my code in a proper place.

Comment: Hi TTCC. Thanks for your time. I don't have expertise in JS. So, having trouble following your suggestion properly. I have edited my question with the entire code from the init.min.js in the plugin folder. I hope with your help, I can locate it and insert now. Please suggest.

Comment: Sorry, I made a error that used a "$" (jQuery object).Now I update it to "a".

Comment: I added the code, but the scroll is working only when I click back the thumbnail to close it. Its not scrolling on the click. Is it something due to stop.animate function? I have mentioned the code as per your suggestion in second block in my original question.
Thanks.

Comment: Please remove the ".cq-expandgrid-item" click event in "/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/js/pcvideo.js" or don't import this pcvideo.js file.

Comment: Made changes. But still acting same way.

Comment: @user2983808 In the init.min.js" file, you should use semicolon ";" not comma "," before my code! It can be placed in a new line.As code have been inserted at end, I missed a symbol "!".See the code of my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks indeed. Happy to see it working now. Thanks alot. The only thing is that, when we click on any thumbnail, when another is opened, its scrolling way down to the end. This may be due to the existing function that was already enabled before we worked on your code. Is there any clear line of code that you could see which we can disable?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$(".cq-expandgrid-item").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $this.find(".cq-expandgrid-content").offset().top
    }, 5000);
});
```

PD: with $(".cq-expandgrid-content").offset().top you where trying get multiple values, because there are many .cq-expandgrid-content" occurrences

Comment: Hi @Toni Michel Caubet, I tried this, but it's doing nothing.